# what to do if foreign key table column doesn't match the parent table column being referred to in oracle + yii framework?

Tags: php, oracle, yii

I have two tables, Table A and Table B.

Now table A has `A.id` and B has `B.id` whereby `B.id` is the foreign key to link with `A.id`

Now my problem is, A has A.extraid that "HAS" many rows in B wherein the column name is `B.notsamextraid`.  In other words, the values of `B.notsamextraid` matches the values of `A.extraid`

What should I do in order to have Yii match these two columns wherein they both have different names ?

(I am not authorize to alter the name of B.notsamextraid into B.extraid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yii documentation says [DO define foreign-key relationships in the database schema](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design/#hh5).

Can you try out the following tables? Yii should be able to pick up both foreign keys:

```
create table a (
  id      int not null primary key,
  extraid int not null unique
);

create table b (
  id            references a(id),
  notsamextraid references a(extraid)
);
```

Edit: To find out if there are already foreign keys between two tables, you can use the following query. It's not the prettiest query on the planet, but then there is copy and paste :-)

```
select t1.owner, t1.constraint_name, t1.constraint_type, t1.table_name, c1.column_name,
       t2.owner, t2.constraint_name, t2.constraint_type, t2.table_name, c2.column_name
  from all_constraints  t1
  join all_cons_columns c1
    on t1.constraint_name=c1.constraint_name
   and t1.owner=c1.owner 
   and t1.table_name=c1.table_name
  join all_constraints  t2
    on t1.owner=t2.owner
   and t1.r_constraint_name=t2.constraint_name
  join all_cons_columns c2
    on t2.constraint_name=c2.constraint_name
   and t2.owner=c2.owner 
   and t2.table_name=c2.table_name
   and c1.position=c2.position
 where t1.constraint_type = 'R'
   and t1.table_name in ('A','B');
```

Comment: I am not authorized to alter the table...am using oracle by the way....isn't there a way to solve that in Yii framework?

Comment: Can you ask the person who set up the tables if there are two foreign key constraints between table b and a?

Comment: i can ask that tomorrow, but aren't there any oracle commands that i can use to run in sql developer to know if there are two key contraints ?

Comment: You have access to sql developer, that's excellent. I've put the query into the answer as I don't know how to put it in a comment.

Comment: If there is no foreign key between `B.notsamextraid` and `A.extraid` then you could try a Yii workaround described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957765/possible-to-fix-a-foreign-key-in-yii-without-having-set-it-up-in-the-database).

Comment: i copy and pasted your query and just substituted the 'A','B' with the real table names.. but no result appeared when i ran it in sql developer

Comment: Oh dear! I'd recommend to ask your database person to declare the missing foreign keys, your code picks up the relationship, the data is protected and the database is faster: `alter table a add constraint pk_a_id primary key (a);
alter table a add constraint uq_q_extraid unique (extraid);
alter table b add constraint fk_b_id foreign key (id) references a(id);
alter table b add constraint fk_b_extraid foreign key (notsamextraid) references a(extraid);
`

Comment: i solved my problem without having to ask any dba to add constraints...i used the createCommand of Yii framework and just binded some paremeters..it's not the nicest way..but atleast it can get the data output that i need even if the two column names doesn't have the same names ..i'll choose this answer of yours as the best answer..maybe some other people will encounter the same problem and get redirected to this page via googling